# Django Admin: admin.sites.register(MyModel) doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

By mistake I deleted the migration files, and now my Admin does not register my Models, apparently because they were already registered and appeared correctly but now they do not appear and do not register them, and also if I try to do 'admin.sites.unregister' it indicates that it's not registered. How do I force djago to register my model again? :(

Here my admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Post, Category
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Category)
```

[image]

Comment: Is your app in INSTALLED_APPS and and are you logged in as a superuser?

Comment: Yes I'm logged in as superuser, and my 'blog' app is in INSTALLED_APPS but doesn't appears. :(

Comment: Are you sure you are a superuser? You cannot see Groups in the auth section

Comment: I created my user with python manage.py createsuperuser, how can I verify it?

Comment: Navigate to your user in the admin and make sure that `is_superuser` is checked

Comment: @IainShelvington my user is marked as superuser, in fact I uncheck it and then I can't access anymore my admin site haha, I had to update directly in DB. :) now I can access again, but no group section is present... :/ 
neither models are present...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199341/discussion-between-eric-ocampo-and-iain-shelvington).

Comment: I need to delete and clone again my project, drop al tables and run migrations agains. now it works.  thanks :)